# Angular Carousel Arrows not showing IOS7

Tags: jquery, ios, css, angularjs, ios7

I have a AngularJS Carousel and the prev/next arrows are not showing in iOS7, though they work fine in iOS8 and desktop browsers. The strange thing if within Safari's devtools I uncheck any element and re-check it (For example position: absolute, or left:9px) they appear and work perfectly. Even if I do not change that property.

Comment: Try disabling the alpha channel.

Answer (score 0):

It was resulting from limited support for "vh" units in properties in IOS7